# What size is the fuse on a watermaster/orbit sprinkler timer box? Blinking red

Tags: circuit-breaker, sprinkler-system

I've got a "watermaster" old sprinkler timer box.  Fuse blew, it's got a blinking red light, what replacement fuse can I use?

Appears same size as this box:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgYUyxFnlaY

It says "750mA slow burn" near the fuse location.

Comment: the fuse part number is printed on the fuse itself

Comment: Yeah when I pulled the old fuse all it said was "750mA 250V" (I think) ... maybe it had been replaced already before?

Comment: Though in retrospect I probably could have looked up the manual for it as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I tried some out from home depot and "5mm by 20mm 1A fast burn" was the closest they stock and seemed to work OK for me.

Appears the canonical replacement is "orbit 57003" but they're sometimes tricky to find/more expensive.  Might be able to find some equivalents [online](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R68QD1WHLO4HM/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0040QPFKU) as well.